# Error SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling .. in target '' from project pods while migrating from objective C to Swift in my react native app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I have a react native sdk inside which all of the code is written in objective C, now we are migrating it to swift, i followed the official react native guide on how to migrate to swift, did everything as suggested there but it's not working, i will explain where the main problem is happening -
so inside my objective c file my code is written like this -

```swift
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <SCDoorway/SCDoorway.h>
#import <SCDoorway/SCDoorway-Swift.h>
#import <Loans/Loans.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BigTreeDoorway, NSObject)

//MARK: SDK version helpers
//MARK: SDK setup
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(setConfigEnvironment,
                 envName:(NSString *)envName
                 gateway:(NSString *)gateway
                 isLeprechaunActive: (BOOL *)isLeprechaunActive
                 isAmoEnabled: (BOOL *)isAmoEnabled
                 preProvidedBrokers: (NSArray *)preProvidedBrokers
                 setConfigEnvironmentWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    NSInteger environment = EnvironmentProduction;

    if([envName isEqualToString:@"production"]) {
        environment = EnvironmentProduction;
    }
    else if([envName isEqualToString:@"development"]) {
        environment = EnvironmentDevelopment;
    } else {
        environment = EnvironmentStaging;
    }

    GatewayConfig *config = [[GatewayConfig alloc]
                             initWithGatewayName:gateway
                             brokerConfig:preProvidedBrokers
                             apiEnvironment:environment
                             isLeprechaunActive:isLeprechaunActive
                             isAmoEnabled:isAmoEnabled];

    [SCDoorway.shared setupWithConfig: config completion:^(BOOL success,NSError * error) {
        if(success) {
            resolve(@(YES));
        } else {
            NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [responseDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:error.code]  forKey:@"errorCode"];
            [responseDict setValue:error.domain  forKey:@"errorMessage"];

            NSError *err = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:error.domain code:error.code userInfo:responseDict];

            reject(@"setConfigEnvironment", @"Env setup failed", err);
        }

    }];
}
//and many more functions ...
```

now even in my objective-C file when i open up the xcode project of my SDK it gives me errors like -

[image]

now if i comment out that particular import it starts to give me error for -

[image]

but then inside the podspec file of my react sdk i have added the dependency SCDoorway -

[image]

moving on, when i build my react project it all builds well, and functions work
i started migrating to swift by adding a swift file with the same name as my objective-C file that is - BigTreeDoorway, so now i have 3 files in total inside my project which are the bridging header class, and BigTreeDoorway.swift and BigTreeDoorway.m
i have checked my objective c bridging header file path and it is alright

now when i converted all the objective functions to swift functions like this -

```
import RCTBridgeModule
import Foundation
import SCDoorway
import React
import Loans

@objc(BigTreeDoorway)
class BigTreeDoorway: NSObject {
        
    @objc func setConfigEnvironment(_ envName: String,
                                    gateway: String,
                                    isLeprechaunActive: Bool,
                                    isAmoEnabled: Bool,
                                    preProvidedBrokers: [Any],
                                    resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                                    rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
        
        var environment = EnvironmentProduction

        switch envName {
        case "production":
            environment = EnvironmentProduction
        case "development":
            environment = EnvironmentDevelopment
        default:
            environment = EnvironmentStaging
        }

        let config = GatewayConfig(gatewayName: gateway,
                                   brokerConfig: preProvidedBrokers,
                                   apiEnvironment: environment,
                                   isLeprechaunActive: isLeprechaunActive,
                                   isAmoEnabled: isAmoEnabled)

        SCDoorway.shared.setup(with: config) { success, error in
            if success {
                resolve(true)
            } else {
                var responseDict: [String: Any] = [
                    "errorCode": error?.code ?? 0,
                    "errorMessage": error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
                ]

                let err = NSError(domain: error?.domain ?? "", code: error?.code ?? 0, userInfo: responseDict)
                reject("setConfigEnvironment", "Env setup failed", err)
            }
        }
    }
```

and then i changed my objectiveC file like this -

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <SCDoorway/SCDoorway.h>
#import <SCDoorway/SCDoorway-Swift.h>
#import <Loans/Loans.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BigTreeDoorway, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(setConfigEnvironment,
                 envName:(NSString *)envName
                 gateway:(NSString *)gateway
                 isLeprechaunActive: (BOOL *)isLeprechaunActive
                 isAmoEnabled: (BOOL *)isAmoEnabled
                 preProvidedBrokers: (NSArray *)preProvidedBrokers
                 setConfigEnvironmentWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
//many more 
@end
```

basically i changed it to a  RCT_EXTERN_METHOD from  RCT_REMAP_METHOD and removed the function definition just the name and params as described in the react native site

i was still getting errors inside xcode for these imports -
[image]

[image]

but then the same was happening inside objectiveC file so i tried building my react project and it won't build now, once it starts building the app after 30 seconds it gives me this error -

```
The following build commands failed:
        SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ BigTreeDoorway.swift /Users/aadityasingh/../../../node_modules/my-sdk-name/ios/BigTreeDoorway.swift (in target 'my-sdk-name' from project 'Pods')
        SwiftCompile normal arm64 /Users/aadityasingh/../../my sample app name where am trying to integrate the sdk/node_modules/my-sdk-name/ios/BigTreeDoorway.swift (in target 'my-sdk-name' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

Am stuck on this problem for the last two weeks now, i don't understand how does the objective file works with the same imports but my swift file fails to do so, please help, i tried few things -

- I tried changing the "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = "arm64 i386"
  inside both the sample app, later i tried it with the my sdk ios project too
  the build error was still there
- i deleted the xcode project from ios folder of the my sdk and the sample app still works perfectly fine, hence only 3 files left - bridging header, swift (swift file being empty with just the class defined) and objc file
- when i import Loans (which is a submodule inside SCDoorway) inside the swift file of my sdk, it does not throw any error and the react project builds but then when i uncomment it's functions which involve using Loans classes (and then i put the RCT_EXTERN_METHODS for the same inside objectiveC class commenting everything else out) it throws another error -

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/aadityasingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-app-name-dnrqbqkvgavrbjasjmzapzzrvjtq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-sdk-name.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BigTreeDoorway-5f1feec19880e569a1329e3d7cbede9a.o /Users/aadityasingh/../new/sample app name/node_modules/sdk name/ios/BigTreeDoorway.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'my-sdk-name' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing -

```
"EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = arm64 i386;
```

inside Pods project and

```
"EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = i386;
```

inside iOS app project of my app compiles the code. hope this helps anyone facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

When I finally figured out what was wrong, it had to do with the version of the pod that the code was using.

Therefore, if you're still having these problems, I advise you to:

- Verify the pod's compatibility to see whether that's the problem.
- Reinstall pods after uninstalling them.

OR

- Delete the derived data.
- Quit Xcode.
- Reopen Xcode.
- Clean build.
- Build
- Update your packages to the latest version
- Check if the framework's repository has released a version that adds
  support for arm64
- Upgrade to the highest patch for your minor or latest and
  verify if the issue persists

OR

Visit this links :

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28777
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/40932
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691640